# Error installing expression web 2 (-2147024873)

Tags: silverlight, microsoft-expression-web

Anybody ever had the error "Installation of the "Microsoft Expression Web 2" product has reported the following error: -2147024873.. " when trying to install Microsoft Expression Web 2 or Microsoft Expression Studio?  This is the error I'm getting, but I can't figure out what the problem is.  I have no beta or RC or pre beta software installed.  I'm using office 2003, already have silverlight and .net 1 ,2 3, 3.5 frameworks installed.  I also have 3.6g hd space free.

Errors I found in the log file are as follows:

```
LIS: wait for package "{90120000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}" to complete caching<br>
LIS failed to cache download "{90120000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C" resource "Setup.xml". Cache Error 0x80070017<br>
Source Resolution aborted<br>
  LIS: start caching file "Setup.xml"<br>
LIS failed to cache download "{90120000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C" resource "branding.xml". Cache Error 0x80070017<br>
Source Resolution aborted<br>
  LIS: start caching file "branding.xml"<br>
LIS failed to cache download "{90120000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C" resource "ShellUI.MST". Cache Error 0x80070017<br>
Source Resolution aborted<br>
  LIS: start caching file "ShellUI.MST"<br>
LIS failed to cache download "{90120000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C" resource "osetupui.dll". Cache Error 0x80070017<br>
Source Resolution aborted<br>
  LIS: start caching file "osetupui.dll"
LIS failed to cache download "{90120000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C" resource "Setup.xml". Cache Error 0x80070017<br>
Source Resolution aborted<br>
Log level changed from: Standard to: Verbose<br>
Error: LIS: Failed to cache download "{90120000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C" resource "Setup.xml". HResult: 0x80070017. <br>
Rolling back chain<br>
12/04/2008 16:11:48 Rolling back package: OfficeMUI.en-us<br>
There appears to be no rollback work to do for package: OfficeMUI.en-us path: C:\Documents and Settings\chaj17\Local Settings\Temp\XSetup_Web_2008_12_4_16_1_21\438d1ac8_d88e_46eb_ba69_11fef34cce74\Office.en-us\OfficeMUI.MSI<br>
Stopping running ose<br>
LIS: start uncaching for download "{90120000-0010-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C"<br>
LIS: finished uncaching for download "{90120000-0010-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C"<br>
LIS: start uncaching for download "{90120000-002C-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C"<br>
LIS: finished uncaching for download "{90120000-002C-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C"<br>
LIS: start uncaching for download "{90120000-0045-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C"<br>
LIS: finished uncaching for download "{90120000-0045-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C"<br>
LIS: start uncaching for download "{90120000-0045-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C"<br>
LIS: finished uncaching for download "{90120000-0045-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C"<br>
LIS: start uncaching for download "{90120000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C"<br>
LIS: finished uncaching for download "{90120000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C"<br>
Stopping running ose<br>
Not showing completion dialog because it was not requested.<br>
Catalyst execution finished: 12/04/2008 16:11:52.  Return code: -2147024873.<br>
PERF: TickCount=3954562 Name=RunSetup Description=End function<br>
=========================================================================<br>
Error: Installation of the "Microsoft Expression Web 2" product has reported the following error: -2147024873.<br>
Info: Config_Products_InstallNew: End installation of new product: Microsoft Expression Web 2<br>
Error: Config_Products_Install: Installation of Product Microsoft Expression Web 2 (failed): Installation of the "Microsoft Expression Web 2" product has reported the following error: -2147024873. Stack:    at XSetup.OfficePackage.ConfigureNewInstall(Product product)    at XSetup.Product.ConfigureNewProduct()<br>
Info: Config_Products_InstallNew: End installation of new product: Microsoft Expression Web 2<br>
Info: Expecting to find local release notes at 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114830'.<br>
Error: XSetup_DoTasks:: Installation of the "Microsoft Expression Web 2" product has reported the following error: Installation of the "Microsoft Expression Web 2" product has reported the following error: -2147024873.. Stack:    at XSetup.XSetupSession.OnDoTasksThreadDoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)<br>
Error: Installation of the "Microsoft Expression Web 2" product has reported the following error: Installation of the "Microsoft Expression Web 2" product has reported the following error: -2147024873..<br>
Info: End Setup session<br>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
Error: XSetup_DoTasks:: Installation of the "Microsoft Expression Web 2" product has reported the following error: Installation of the "Microsoft Expression Web 2" product has reported the following error: -2147024873.. Stack:    at XSetup.XSetupSession.OnDoTasksThreadDoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed Office 2007, try to uninstall it. Otherwise, uninstall it manually as per the instructions at http://support.microsoft.com/KB/928218.

Then reinstall Office 2007 and install Expression Web. Then, it should work.

Comment: I uninstalled everything I could find relating to office.  Eventually got tired of looking and rebuilt my pc.  worked fine after that :)

Answer (score 0):

The error code here (-2147024873) corresponds to 0x80070017 in hex, which is really HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_CRC):

```
Data error (cyclic redundancy check)
```

I'm not sure if you're installing this application from a DVD or from an installer you downloaded, but perhaps the installation sources are corrupt?  If the other suggestions on this page don't seem to help, you might consider re-downloading the installation binaries and trying again.  Not sure if it will fix your problem, but it's worth a shot if all else fails...

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem when installing blend. I jus copied the extracted setup files from the temp folder to a another location before the "send error report" screen. I started the setup using Blend_en.msi . Thats it, installation was successful. :) .